# Opening a Python file in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I open a Python .py file in the VS Code Explorer, file path also opens along with the Python file? How can I dis-able this feature? I find this very annoying!

Thanks you!

Tried searching the json file and settings buy I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "file path also opens along with the python file"?

Comment: The location of the file appears  on the workspace. i.e. c:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop....

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate directly to the python.py file, and then you can right click, and press "open with", then "Visual Studio Code"

Comment: Or the other way using File>Open File...

Comment: Thank you but that does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

1. Open your settings.
2. Search for **breadcrumbs**
3. Uncheck `Breadcrumbs: Enable` **or** Trun `Breadcrumbs: File Path` to  off(suggeste)

[image]